Generate palindromic numbers
The formula
Here a function $F$ that produces palindromic numbers for all natural numbers called $n$.
$$F(n) = \left\lfloor \frac{10^{\left\lfloor \log_{10}(n) \right\rfloor + 1} - 1}{9} \right\rfloor \times 10^{\left\lfloor \log_{10}(n) \right\rfloor} + \left\lfloor \frac{10^{\left\lfloor \log_{10}(n) \right\rfloor + 1} - 1}{9} \right\rfloor$$
We can observe that the palindromic numbers that are generated (excepted for 2) ending and beginning with 1.
Example
With n=11 we have:
$$F(n) = \left\lfloor \frac{10^{\left\lfloor \log_{10}(11) \right\rfloor + 1} - 1}{9} \right\rfloor \times 10^{\left\lfloor \log_{10}(11) \right\rfloor} + \left\lfloor \frac{10^{\left\lfloor \log_{10}(11) \right\rfloor + 1} - 1}{9} \right\rfloor=121$$
And 121 is a palindromic number.
The question is: are there other palindromic numbers ending and beginning with another digit that 1.

This is hard to follow.  Of course there are palindromes that start and end with something besides $1$.  Is that really what you are asking?  Also...your basic formula uses $n$ on both sides...it doesn't seem like the $n$ on the left is the same as the $n$ on the right.  Did you mean $F(n)$ on the left, or something like that?

Yes I mean $F(n)$ on the left, sorry.

And what is the question?  The second term in your expression consists of a string of $1's$, regardless of what $n$ is.  So...of course $F(n)$ ends with $1$.  Is that what you are asking?

lulu: I mean that I can generate only palindromic numbers with the digits 1 and 2 only. For example 121 is a palindromic number returned by this function.

Yes, that's true.  What is the question?

The question is: is it possible to obtain palindromic numbers with other digits than 1 and 2.

If $\lfloor\log_{10}(n)\rfloor = k$ then $F(n)$ will produce $\underbrace{111.....11}{k-1}2\underbrace{111.....11}{k-1}$.  Those are the only palindromic numbers your formula will produce.  So the answer to you question is ... no.

Using this expression?  Obviously not.  The first term is a string of $1's$ followed by a string of $0's$.  The second is a string of $1's$.  Oof course the sum is a string of $1's$ followed by a string of $2's$ followed by a string of $1's$.

"The question is: is it possible to obtain palindromic numbers with other digits than 1 and 2."  Not from this formula.

Thanks for your responses. Is it an interesting formula?

". Is it an interesting formula?"  No.  It isn't.

FOr any $k$ we have $\frac {10^{k+1} - 1}9 = \underbrace{111....1}k$.  So $\frac {10^{k+1}-1}9 \times 10^{k-1}=\underbrace{1111....1111}k\underbrace{000...0}{k-1}$ and  $\frac {10^{k+1}-1}9 \times 10^{k-1}+\frac {10^{k+1}-1}9=11111......111121111......1$.  You can plug in any natural number for $k$.  Tossing an $n$ and converting it to the natural number $\lfloor \log_{10}n\rfloor$ only assures the resulting natural number with have about one more digit than $n$.  Otherwise any number can get tossed it.

By the way, since your fractions are already integers (numerator is always a multiple of $9$), wrapping each of them in the floor function needlessly complicates the formula.

Are you certain that this function is rigorous? It could be that the function happens to interpolate the palindromes up to some bound $N > 121$, and indeed you haven't shown some more involved examples (for example can you generate 12321, or indeed all of the palindromes, or does your function just hit some palindromes up to a bound?)
Apologies I cannot comment, otherwise I would put this there.

No I can't generate 12321, I can generate only palindromic numbers with the digits 2 and 1.

Okay, is it possible to obtain 12221? Or 12121. Also it is possible to factorise your formula as $(10^(floor(log_10(n))) + 1) * floor(expression)))

It's only possible to generate number of the form $11111......11111211111....111111$, with a single $2$ smack in the middle with equal numbers of $1$s to the right and left.

Thanks @fleablood, I think in terms of whether the formula is interesting, I would say the ratio of interesting results produced to complexity of formula is low.

It essentially does this:  Take a number $n$, count its digits-- it then creates a number with one fewer $1$s, a $2$, and another set of $1$s.

@fleablood Yeah that is the parsing.
